# Вывод одного значения из разных полей

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, php, sql

Помогите, плиз. :)

Ситуация такая: из базы хочу вывести все записи под значением, к примеру, 6, это значение может хранится в нескольких РАЗНЫХ полях. Еак составить запрос?

http://rghost.ru/8gqG2PNYF.view

Comment: @lidovsci, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE row1=6 and row2=6 and ... rowN=6;
```

перечисли все нужные поля.

или

```
SELECT * WHERE MATCH (text) AGAINST ('$find')
```

Comment: Проблема в том, что на первом поле если нет записи, то остальное он больше не ищет.

Comment: поставь OR!, а не AND. Чуть-чуть ведь подумать нужно, немного включить соображалку.

Comment: не работает твой метод

Comment: необоснованно как-то...

Comment: он выводит все в подряд, кроме этих записей, а их не выводит

Comment: приведи пример своего запроса сюда!

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE 6 in(`row1`,`row2`,`rowN`);
```